# Nokia HERE Maps API Historical Traffic Data

Tags: here-api

Does the HERE API take into account historical traffic data when routing with traffic enabled? For example, if I set the departure time to 5PM local time for a date either in the future or the past (not today) I would expect to get a traffic time greater than the base time due to rush hour traffic.

It doesn't seem to work though. The traffic time and base time come back with the same value. I can't tell if this API just doesn't support this, if it's a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is a sample request from the API Playground (with the demo App ID and key) set to 5PM as an example of what I'm referring to:

http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&departure=2015-03-27T17:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation suggests Historic Data is not considered for Routing, only current data is considered

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/private-transport-routing-traffic-enabled.html

"Enabling traffic allows the Routing API to consider up-to-date traffic information when calculating a route. If the route calculation is performed for the current time, traffic information will be based on current data. Calculations for future times will only consider long term road closures."

Comment: I came across this answer and just want to point out that Here API now also considers historic data.